# Calling for multiple onclick functions?

Tags: html, function, onclick

I have been looking for a solution for this for a long time and I just could not find what I was looking for. I have made a code that is an automatic traffic light and it loops through. How can I change it so when I click it goes through the sequence and stops when it gets back to Red?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body onload="startTime();">
<img id="img1" />
<script>
var imgArray = new Array("Red.jpg","RedA.jpg","Green.jpg","Amber.jpg");
var imgCount = 0;
function startTime() {
    if(imgCount == imgArray.length) {
        imgCount = 0;
    }
    document.getElementById("img1").src = imgArray[imgCount];
    imgCount++;
    setTimeout("startTime()", 1000);
}
</script>
</body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Multiple solutions: 1. using counter 2. use for

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change setTimeout function syntax.

```
setTimeout(function(){
  startTime();
},1000);
```

[Check working example](https://jsfiddle.net/PratapRockers/fjx4xxq9/)